# CGIHTTPServer: Error code 403

Tags: python, cgi

i got a:

> Error response Error code 403.  Message: CGI script is not executable
>   ('/cgi-bin/main.pyc').  Error code explanation: 403 = Request
>   forbidden -- authorization will not help.

while tying to run a compiled python script (.pyc) on a python CGIHTTPServer. normal python scripts (.py) are working fine.
cgi server looks like this:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
from CGIHTTPServer import CGIHTTPRequestHandler

class CGIServer(HTTPServer):
    def __init__(self, (hostname,port), handler):
        HTTPServer.__init__(self, (hostname, port), handler)
srvaddr = ("", 8000)
cgisrv = CGIServer(srvaddr,CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
cgisrv.serve_forever()
```

is there any possibility to get this working on windows? .pyc files are linked like .py files under windows. even google can't tell me more.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to run `.pyc` files, not `.py` ones? I don't think `CGIHTTPServer` can run something apart from true executables (`.exe`) and scripts, which are text files with `#!` on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

`.pyc` files are compiled Python scripts, meant to be run on their own. I am rather sure that `CGIHTTPServer` cannot run compiled Python files, only scripts with the `.py` extension.

Is there any reason you can't use a `.py` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a tiny wrapper (in normal python) to load the other code as a module.

For more details, please consider the python tutorial [1] and its comments:

- > A program doesn't run any faster when it is read from a ".pyc" or
  >   ".pyo" file than when it is read from a ".py" file; the only thing
  >   that's faster about ".pyc" or ".pyo" files is the speed with which
  >   they are loaded.
- > When a script is run by giving its name on the command line, the
  >   bytecode for the script is never written to a ".pyc" or ".pyo" file.
  >   Thus, the startup time of a script may be reduced by moving most of
  >   its code to a module and having a small bootstrap script that imports
  >   that module.

FYI - I just tested CGIHTTPServer with a script and the compiled version 
of that same script.  I got the error you noted, and when I tried to run
the two versions on the command line, running the `.py` version printed
the expected output, and running the `.pyc` version caused a bunch of 
garbage to be printed on the terminal (I didn't bother to investigate the
exact source).  In summary - double check that you can run a program on
the command line as a basic test.

[1] http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/node43.html